# Android Mapview show white tiles without any map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-widget

I generated `MD5` and `SHA` `fingerprint` for my `android application`. Then I went to google to get an `map api for android with SHA`. Because I havent seen any place in google to get api with `MD5`. Even I set `INTERNET permission` in `manifest file` and define my layout as below ,google map is not seen in my activity

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/mapview1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:enabled="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="AIzaSyCfaFYAg1ql6hHN..."
```

Furthermore I saw in a article that if I get api key with SHA fingerprint it will not work. But Google asks for only SHA for api key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me answer my question which I was expecting to get a solution from SO society.

1. Be sure you have installed Google Play servise
2. Then get the `google-play-services_lib` from `C:\Program
       Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`
       as `Android Project From Existing Code` into your workspace
3. Add this to your project `Library` as
   (Project->Properties->Android->Library->Add)
4. And then all you need to complete using google map in your app is
       getting a key from google. Just enough to follow instructions at the
       bottom of `Creating an API Project` at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key
5. That's all. have fun with SO

Answer (score 0):

if the map is not showing up then it is something with your key. You need 2 different keys, one for when you debug and one for when you release to the market

Comment: How can I do that. I really do not have any idea about that. All tutorials I found on internet are old and google changed many things

Comment: Why are you using Google Map v1 anyway you should be using v2 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start